# OpenCL local int pointers hangs GPU, works fine on CPU

Tags: c, performance, gpu, opencl, cpu

I'm trying different things related to OpenCL 1.2 and 2.0. I found a topic called Generic Address Space and tried some things with pointers. Can someone please tell me why this code executes fine on my CPU (Intel i3 reporting OpenCL 2.1) and hangs for 2 minutes on my NVIDIA GeForce 940MX.

```
void first(int *ptr) {
  *ptr = 2;
}

__kernel void sampleKernel(__global const float *a, __global float *d) {
    __private int gid = get_global_id(0);
    __private int group_id = get_group_id(0);
    __local int *ptr1;
    ptr1 = 0;
    first(&ptr1);
    printf("ptr1: %u\n", ptr1);
}
```

I'm not expecting any kind of specific behavior regaring this code in terms of local int pointer, but would like to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Looks like undefined behavior to me... Shouldn't it be `__local int ptr1;` instead of `__local int *ptr1;`?

Comment: @Jardel Lucca yes.

Comment: As you say, bevahior may be undefined, so it is why it either works or not on some devices. I have some other examples which works fine on regular GCC on CPU and doing the same on OpenCL C I get different results. Is there something important to remember while doing pointer math or addressing things in OpenCL?

Comment: It really must be `__local int ptr1;`, otherwise you set the value 0 as the address of the pointer. OpenCL can do pointer arithmetic just like C99, but when passing variables to functions, the address space must match. You can either write `void first(__local int *ptr)` or you cast `ptr` to `__private int` before calling `first`.

Answer (score 0):

Generic address space has been introduced in the OpemCL 2.0 specification, but is not  yet allowed in the OpenCL 1.2 specification. Intel supports 2.0, but Nvidia supports only 1.2. If you explicitly set the address space of the function parameter to local, it should also work on the 940MX. Otherwise, the function parameter is implicitly treated as private memory space in OpenCL 1.2.

Comment: 940MX specs say that it supports up to OpenCL 3.0. I'm using  460.91.03 driver in Ubuntu, but not sure which versions the SDK/compiler picks by default.

Comment: @Michal Sobczak OpenCL 3.0 is identical to 1.2 but with a higher number and with OpenCL 2.X features being optional. OpenCL 3.0 does mit support generic address space either, but OpenCL 2.X does.